# unsupproted projection option while querying children elements mongdb with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am working on a query to a mongodb with mgo using golang but it throws `Unsupported projection option` error while querying a sub document.

I am working on below document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b64a0d3931653c36bcaf0b5"),
    "quantity" : 2,
    "product" : "ABC",   
    "children" : [ 
        {           
            "isBlocked" : true,
            "blockedMessage" : "Error occurred: TRACEID",
            "serialNo" : "abc123",
            "token" : "foo456",            
        }
    ]
}
```

The query I am using is

```
bson.M{"_id": 0, "children": bson.M{"serialNo": "abc123"}}
```

**May I know where the mistake is?**

Answer (score 1):

Matching array element should be done with [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Raw mongodb query looks like:

```
db.collection.find({_id: ObjectId('...'), children: {$elemMatch: {serialNo: 'abc123'}}});
```

Comment: Thanks! but this returns only the sub document "children", is there way I could get the entire document?

Comment: This should return entire document. You should double check yor query

Comment: I tried this query but only get children `bson.M{"_id": 0, "children": bson.M{"$elemMatch": {serialNo: 'abc123'}}}`